# Solve "unchecked warning" in Java avoiding @suppressWarnings

Tags: java, generics, unchecked

This is a *Trying to improve my code* question. About generics and the unchecked warning; I do know about the `@suppresswarnings` annotation. The question is **what am I suppose to code to suppress it**. Take, please, the following code.

```
public class NumericBox<T extends Number> implements Box<T> {

    private T element;


    public NumericBox(T element) {
        this.element = element;
    }

    @Override public T getElement() {
        return element;
    }

    public T insert(Number newElement) {
        T oldElement = this.element;
        this.element = (T) newElement; // warning("unchecked")
        return oldElement;
    }
}
```

What is the coding way to do this (not the annotation). In the docs I've found 
*The term "unchecked" means that the compiler does not have enough type information to perform all type checks necessary to ensure type safety.* But, don't get it. This seems ok for me:

```
void foo(Number n) {
    Short asShort = (Short) n; //OK
    T  asTypeWhichExtendsNumber = (T) n; // warning
}
```

Extra. if I want to add an empty constructor, is any way to keep a "ZERO" in element?

```
NumeircBox<Short> o = new NumericBox<>(); // expectes 0 in the element
```

Comment: Why is the method signature not `T insert(T newElement)`?

Comment: Imagine you really want a method just for NumericBoxes, not every box, and that method needs to receive a Number, not every T. Probably I should change to something using compareTo()

Comment: I looked for a scenario for the warning, try to imagine that you really want the signature. If necessary I change the scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets look at the code in question, your `class` declaration:

```
public class NumericBox<T extends Number> implements Box<T>
```

So we have some type `T` that `extends Number`. This might be `Long`, `Integer` etc. But some **specific** and **defined at compile time** type.

Now you have a method:

```
public T insert(Number newElement) {
    T oldElement = this.element;
    this.element = (T) newElement;
    return oldElement;
}
```

Which takes some `Number` of any type - neither **specfic** nor **defined at compile time** and you coerce it into a `T`. **This is a `ClassCastException` waiting to happen**.

```
final NumericBox<BigDecimal> box = new NumericBox<>();
box.insert(3);
final BigDecimal val = box.getElement();  <-- OOPS!
```

There is no way to avoid this warning because the compiler is telling you example this, you have an unchecked cast that could, at runtime, cause a `ClassCastException`. The compiler is *washing its hands* of that line.

So, to solve your problem, change the code to:

```
public T insert(T newElement) {
    T oldElement = this.element;
    this.element = (T) newElement;
    return oldElement;
}
```

As generics are erased at compile time, there is not really *any* way of fixing that hack. If you want to guarantee runtime type safety you need to change the signature. If you want to take "any old `Number`" then you will have to deal with the consequences.

Comment: Like your reply. But let me ask 2 things. Is it possible then to use Number (the superclass of my generic type along my class). Second your code (OOPS code) works for me, I tried it twice (bigdecimal and short) :S

Comment: @manutero, slightly misread your original code - updated the error condition. Don't understand your first point re `Number`.

Comment: see the exception. About the other point. If you have class A<T extends S> how do you use S (super class) along the class (for example in method's signatures). Hope that is the correct question :)

Comment: You use `S` _inside_ the `class A` - it guarantees that methods available on `S` are available for any `T`. Outside of the `class` you use the concrete type `T`. For an example, look at the usage of the `Collection` API.

Answer (score 1):

Declare the "insert" method as taking a parameter of type T, not Number. Right now the caller can pass any Number, not just the one which matches the T type parameter of your class, and you'll get a ClassCastException at runtime if the type doesn't match.